# Rbt Post Pre-commit Throwing Error Message

Tags: github

Hi All i m tring to post review for my pre-committed files using the command
rbt post --parent=master but i m getting the following error message:-

**WARNING: Your working directory is not clean. Any changes which have not been committed to a branch will not be included in your review request.
ERROR: There don't seem to be any diffs!**

Someone please help.

Comment: Note: I have'nt even committed changes on my local git repo.coz i just want to post review for my indexed files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you have untracked files and that’s why there is nothing to add in review request